# Font styling when annotating Sphinx toctree

Tags: python-sphinx, toctree

I'm trying to build documentation for a Python project using Sphinx (using autodoc with the readthedocs theme). I want to override the text in the table of contents side bar. Following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38836458/annotated-sphinx-toctree/43493103#comment130939863_43493103), I can achieve this by modifying the toctree in index.rst

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   This is an annotation <thisisthenameoftherstfile>
```

In the table of contents side-bar in HTML, this now renders as

```
This is an annotation
```

rather than

```
thisisthenameoftherstfile
```

So far so good; Sadly, I can't seem to style text this way. For example

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   **modulename**: *Routines for thing* <thisisthenameoftherstfile>
   <b>modulename</b>: <i>Routines for thing<i> <thisisthenameoftherstfile>
```

Renders in the HTML, sadly, as

```
   **modulename**: *Routines for thing*
   <b>modulename</b>: <i>Routines for thing</i>
```

I'm a little surprised that `<b></b>` etc render verbatim, as I thought you could only do this using the `<pre>` tag. I've tried inspecting the CSS in the browser and I can't figure out what property is causing these tags to be ignored / rendered as text rather than interpreted as text styling. Evidently markdown styling isn't interpreted either.

Is there any way to fix this? I'd like to see things like

- Module **named_module**: *I do this thing*

In the side bar, where the content of the annotation text is bespoke to each table-of-contents entry, and defined entirely at the top-level `index.rst` file only (so, not part of the information in the lower-level `.rst` files i.e. `thisisthenameoftherstfile.rst` in this example.)

Comment: reStructuredText does not support interpreted inline formatting of toctree elements. However you could try [MyST](https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and see if that supports it. I have not tried it myself, but I do know that MyST supports styled links.

Comment: @StevePiercy: Any idea what attributes Sphinx gives the toctree HTML elements to cause it to ignore HTML text formatting commands like this? My intuition is that HTML font styling codes could work with some post-hoc modification that allows the toctree contents in the generated HTML to be interpreted, well, as HTML.

Comment: To expound, I tried adding the e.g. `<i>` `</i>` styling to the toctree text in the browser using "inspect element", and the tags still render verbatim rather than changing the text to italic. I searched and couldn't find any notable attribute that was set that could cause this? But maybe the "edit contents" in Firefox's "inspect element" isn't doing what I'm assuming it does.